# +4 rep for an upvote, meta and main site rep don't match

Tags: bug

I'm not usually one to quibble about reputation, but i'm curious about this

Answer gets upvoted

[image]

I get +4 rep rather than +10

[image]

I've obviously not been downvoted, and my daily rep is 190. Did i hit on a bug of some sort?

Edit: in addition SU rep is at 34220 and MSU rep is at 34216. I'm assuming its due to some delay in syncing.

Comment: I've about to head home so haven't time for a full answer, but check out your rep change list, sorted by time, and you'll see that you would have hit the rep cap, except that a vote was invalidated (lowering you to 190) as a user was deleted at about 14:30 UTC. I guess the system hasn't taken that in to account correctly.

Comment: diff in rep is because of sync timings, they're the same now. link to the answer?

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/438822/10165

Comment: [Reputation History](http://superuser.com/reputation)